# Array space being reused in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have following loop (part of a program that does decryption):

```java
for(int i=0; i < inputd.length; i++){
        byte[] blockd = this.fromHex(inputd[i]);
        byte[] pt = cipher.doFinal(blockd); // Problem?

        if(plainText == null)
            plainText = new String(pt);
        else
            plainText+=new String(pt);
}
```

In the marked statement, `cipher.doFinal(blockd)` returns arrays of different sizes. The problem is if in an iteration array of size say 30 is returned and in next iteration say its 25 (smaller) then assignment replaces first 25 characters and last 5 chars of previous iteration are still in the array.

This is `fromHex()` function:

```java
    private byte[] fromHex(String b){
            byte[] bt = (new BigInteger(b, 16)).toByteArray();
            if(bt.length > 64){
                bt = Arrays.copyOfRange(bt, 1, 65);
            }
            return bt;
    }
```

How should I solve this? Assigning null to both before loop end doesn't help.

Comment: ArrayList to store array of bytes, doesn't sound good. It should be last resort

Answer (score 1):

Since each time you are creating new instance of byte[]pt  in each iteration , So there is no need to worry about the previous size of this array .
Try using this method to convert hex. String to byte array

```
private byte[] toBytes(String s)
{
    int len = s.length();     
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];     
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) 
    {         
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)+ Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));     
    }     
    return data; 
}
```

Comment: I should not need to worry, but this is what is happening. I have added fromHex functio in the question. Check it if that helps.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `BigDecimal(String val)` ?

Comment: what would that do? I am trying to convert a string that is in hex format back to byte array